# Is there a way to connect a high quality mic to qwiic connector

Tags: port, microcontroller, converters, microphone

I am developing an microcontroller project which requires recording audio the only ports free are QWIIC and MCP3008 ADC is there any way to integrate the mic into the system so that the os recognises it
Thanks in advance

I tried searching on Google to fing some solution expecting to geta converter but found nothing as a result

Comment: As written I'm unclear what you're doing. QWIIC is a vendor-specific connector system for digital signals that are passed between integrated circuits. It isn't intended for analog audio, though there may be an I2C ADC that someone has put on a QWIIC-compatible board. The MCP3008 uses SPI, a different and incompatible digital communications standard. Also, microcontrollers usually do not have an OS -- are you also trying to interface this system with a desktop computer? That adds complexity. Please edit your post with more details about your design and your goals.

Comment: Also, once you've clarified your design, if your question involves interfacing audio with a microcontroller you may find better answers over at https://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: i have just left the project @MattS